# What's wrong with this C library function usage?

Tags: c

I am trying to compare two char arrays. The DoSomething() function, however, never get's called. I can't figure out why.

What am I doing wrong?

```
//The value the user types in will be stored here:
char TempStorage[]={0,0,0,0,0,0};

//User types in a sequence here:
GetInput();

//One of the sequences that TempStorage will be compared to.
char Sequence[]={1,2,3,4,0,0};


//If the user typed in "123400" then DoSomething().
if(memcmp(TempStorage, Sequence, sizeof(TempStorage) == 0))
{
    DoSomething();
}
```

Comment: Yoy may want to initialize Sequence this way `char Sequence[]={'1','2','3','4',0,0};`

Comment: What does your GetInput() function do ? Perhaps it assigns ascii digits to your `TempStorage`. Perhaps it has a another bug.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Misplaced paren.

```
if(memcmp(TempStorage, Sequence, sizeof(TempStorage) == 0))
```

should be

```
if(memcmp(TempStorage, Sequence, sizeof(TempStorage)) == 0)
```

---

Are those really six inputs that you parsed and placed in an array? Or is `TempStorage` a string of ASCII characters that was input? If it's the latter, you should be using a string comparison, and you should be using the proper ASCII codes for the character you want to compare. (This is `0x30` or `'1'' for`1`.) A string comparison stops as soon as one of the strings is a NUL (`'\0'`), meaning you don't compare meaningless padding if any exists.

```
char *input = GetInput();
if (strcmp(input, "1234") == 0) { ... }
```

Comment: I think that is just a typo when entering the question here. The real issue is the string he is comparing against or maybe not.... guess that would fail too!

Comment: @AnthonyLambert, yeah, it was bugging me from the start. i finally added a bit on that in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

your characters will resolve to ASCII values so you should specify it as:

```
 char Sequence[]={'1','2','3','4',0,0};
```

Or compare against an actual string like:

```
char Sequence[]="1234";
```